# How to load js .click just after a div is dynamically included

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

i have a div wich content is dinamically loaded into it with jquery .load event.

example:

```
<div data-role="content">
<!-- dinamic loaded content with .load-->
    <input type="button" id="hi" />
<!-- end of loaded content-->
</div>
```

i Have on header a .js loaded contaning

```
$(function() { 
   $("#hi").click(function() {
       alert("hi");
  });
});
```

As the div is not there when the js is loaded, the click event is not triggering, the solucion is on jquerymobile click event? what can i do to workaround this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('click', '#hi', function(){
     alert('hi');
})
```

I choose `document` but it should be the closest non-dynamic parent.

Comment: thanks, worked perfectly, it also doesnt get styled by the css included, any workaround?

Comment: What CSS? If you style your dynamic `div` with CSS files, there shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: @Enoque Duarte: Ask this as another question and someone will tell you what is a problem with your styling.

Comment: Thank you my friends =), i got this